# HQL Calculations in 'case when' not returning decimal

Tags: decimal, hql, case, case-when

In an HQL statement I am calculating  metric_ty in my select statement and when flag_ty is 'Zero' then metric_ly takes the value 0 otherwise metric_ly is calculated. 
My problem is that metric_ty gives back decimal values(eg: 54.32) while metric_ly does not(eg:54.00).

I want to know why this happens and how can i return decimal values inside an case-when loop?

```
 select (p.total_revenue/p.total_units) as metric_ty, 
    (case 
    when flag_ty = 'Zero' THEN 0  ELSE 
    (total_revenue_ly/total_units_ly) END)
    as metric_ly
    from Com p
```

Is it possible to use case-when statements and get exact numbers and not rounding off?

All suggestions are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Data type is chosen based to first scalar expression (0). Problem can be solved by using 0.0 instead of 0:

```
SELECT (p.total_revenue/p.total_units) AS metric_ty, 
    (CASE
      WHEN flag_ty = 'Zero' THEN 0.0 
      ELSE (total_revenue_ly/total_units_ly) END)
    END metric_ly
FROM Com p
```